# Clearing directive scope variables on $destroy

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

On my radio buttons, I have a directive that binds to the `change` event and sets the `ngModel` defined on the element with the radio buttons value. This works fine.

However, the radio buttons can be <s>hidden</s> removed from the DOM based on the user's selection and I want to clear those variables in my controller when this happens. I have a handler for the `$destroy` event in which I set the scopes `ngModel` value to `undefined`.

For some reason setting the scopes value in `$destroy` is not being changed in my controller while setting it in the `change` handler does.

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in category.items" class="field">
    <div class="ui radio checkbox">
        <input type="radio" value="{{item}}" sm-radio-button ng-model="submissions[category.model]" name="{{category.name}}" checked="" tabindex="0" class="hidden">
        <label ng-bind="item"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Directive**:

```
.directive('smRadioButton', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){

            //Instantiate checkbox on load and set value to undefined
            element.parent().checkbox();
            scope.ngModel = undefined;


            element.on('$destroy', function(){
              scope.ngModel = undefined;
            })            

            element.on('change', function(e){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.ngModel = attrs.value;
                });
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Where `category` is one of many config objects like:

```
  {
    name: 'Type',
    model: 'type',
    alwaysShow: true,
    items: ['Spending','Bills','Account Transfer','Deposit']
  },
```

**Note**: I am not using `scope.$apply` in `$destroy` because there is already a digest cycle in progress. `$destroy` is actually being triggered.

**Edit**: Tested this on a few other elements, it seems that in `$destroy` only what appears to be a local scope of that variable is changed? If I reference directly to the controller through `scope.$parent` the controller variable does change. (This is not ideal since this is several ng-repeats deep which means chaining a bunch of `$parent`s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `NgModelController` methods instead.

Taken from the [`NgModelController` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController):

> NgModelController provides API for the ngModel directive. The controller contains services for data-binding, validation, CSS updates, and value formatting and parsing. **It purposefully does not contain any logic which deals with DOM rendering or listening to DOM events.** Such DOM related logic should be provided by other directives which make use of NgModelController for data-binding to control elements. Angular provides this DOM logic for most input elements. At the end of this page you can find a custom control example that uses ngModelController to bind to contenteditable elements.

You should use `$setViewValue` and then, as highlighted above, due to the nature of the API you need to call [`$render`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$render) to update the view:

```
.directive('smRadioButton', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){

            //Instantiate checkbox on load and set value to undefined
            element.parent().checkbox();

            // set the view value
            ctrl.$setViewValue(undefined);

            // render the changes
            ngModel.$render();

            element.on('$destroy', function(){
              ctrl.$setViewValue(undefined);
              ngModel.$render();
            });

            element.on('change', function(e){
                ctrl.$setViewValue(attrs.value);
                ngModel.$render();
            });

        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Edit: comment not-applicable anymore. Thank you for your reply, however I did mention "$destroy is actually being triggered.". The destroy event is being triggered as the element is being removed from the DOM as part of an ng-repeat. I removed my `console.log()`s to keep this easier to read.

Comment: This works great! However, I do need to include a require: 'ngModel' bit in there. What's the use of $render if thats done automatically?

Comment: Because your manually updating the view value which doesn't trigger `ngModelWatch()`

Answer (score 2):

For setting up ngModel value you could use `ngModel.$setViewvalue(undefined)` but for the same you have to require `ngModel` to acquire `ngModelController` inside your `link` function of directive.

Also you could use `$parse` API to set value to `ngModel` directive(without requiring `ngModel` controller there for directive).

So there you could get rid of `isolated scope`(not sure what exactly this directive is doing, it its what you have only shown in code then there in no need to have isolation)

**Directive**

```
.directive('smRadioButton', function(){
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
            //var getter = $parse($attrs.ngModel);
            //setter = getter.assign;
            //Instantiate checkbox on load and set value to undefined
            element.parent().checkbox();

            element.on('$destroy', function(){
              ngModel.$setViewValue(undefined);
              //setter($scope, undefined);
            })            

            element.on('change', function(e){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(attrs.value);
                    //setter($scope, attrs.value);
                });
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: Thanks! both these answers address the problem perfectly. I did not even know about NgModelController or how/when it should be used. Thank you.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell look at another update in my answer, that would explain how you can do it without `ngModelController`, Thanks ;)

Comment: Ah! I see, so much that I don't know about Angular, even after a year. Thanks! Wish I could accept two answers.